# RichTextBox delete old output, and set new output when clicking a button

Tags: c#, input, output, richtextbox

In my C# project I have a read-only `RichTextBox`, a `TextBox` for the input and a button. 
When the user types text, than the output is written in the `RichTextBox` when they push the button.

But if they type more text, the old text is still in this `RichTextBox` and the new text is appended.

How can I delete the old output by clicking the button and at once indicate the new output?

Thank you very much indeed!

-Valeria-

Comment: Is the RichTextBox always empty at start ?

Comment: Add this to your button's `Click` method. `richTextBox1.Text = textBox1.Text;`

Comment: @Raphael Althaus: No, it is not.

Comment: @Batu Zet: Hm, but my output looks like this: richTextBoxResult.AppendText(search.ResultOutcome.ToString());

Comment: Yes. But `AppendText` means add this. `Text` means dont add but make directly this. I thought this is what you want

Comment: richTextBoxResult.Text = "";
richTextBoxResult.AppendText(search.ResultOutcome.ToString());

Comment: @Batu Zet: Oh, thank you!! It's quite easy :-/ the whole day I sit there and cannot solve this problem. See, I'm only a beginner :) Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string newstring =txtInput.Text;
richTextBox.Text+=newString;
```